# profile connect_time is taking time more then useal

Tags: oracle

I have assigned the below profile on the user that I am logged in

```
-- Create profile 
create profile APP_USER limit
  connect_time 1;
-- Add users to profile 
alter user scripts profile APP_USER;
```

however the below execution is taking normal time( 106,321 seconds)

```
declare var number(14);
begin
select count(1) into var from ort; 
select count(1) into var from ort; 
select count(1) into var from ort; 
end;
/
```

shouldnt be 60 seconds ? and yes I am able to run queries afterward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `Resource_Limit` was set to off , it should be changed to true.

```
Alter system set Resource_Limit = True
/
show parameter resource_limit
/
```

Then I loged in into the database again , and it worked.